# Condense multiple for loops into list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How would I do the following in a list comprehension?

```
asins = []
for item in data['message']['body']['titles']:
    for format in item['formats']:
        for offer in format['offers']:
            asins.append(offer['asin'])
```

Comment: See the `combs` example in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the `append()`-contained expression to the front, remove the colons and add brackets around the whole expression:

```
asins = [offer['asin']
    for item in data['message']['body']['titles']
        for format in item['formats']
            for offer in format['offers']]
```

The order of `for` statements otherwise doesn't change. We can now change the indentation and perhaps join the lines if you so wish:

```
asins = [offer['asin']
         for item in data['message']['body']['titles']
         for format in item['formats']
         for offer in format['offers']]
```